# How to load images in twig from root directory folder in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm new in Symfony and my problem is simple, I just can't load images from a certain directory and display it to twig. I have this upload folder located in the root directory of my Symfony project (outside of web folder). This folder is just a link to other VM through Linux file system and which has the original upload folder. I've tried to check if it exists using php's

```
file_exists('/var/www/html/<projname>/upload/somefolder/image.png');
```

and it shows that the image exists but when I'm trying to display the images in twig, it always shows 404 error not found and the image is not displaying. I've already did this:

```
<img src="/var/www/html/<projname>/upload/somefolder/image.png" />
```

and

```
<img src="/upload/somefolder/image.png" />
```

How does `symfony` handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the path of your root directory you can try below code. [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/controller/upload_file.html) is a best example provided for file uploading.

```
$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web' . $this->getRequest()->getBasePath();
```

Might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122789/php-twig-relative-paths-for-images) can also help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized that this image cache bundle http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/introduction.html would be helpful in rendering images.

Comment: @KevinNicolliCunanan Its for older version of symfony !!

Comment: @Tiger this is not true, LiipImagingeBundle can work with symfony 2.3 and higher, and with symfony 3.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `asset()` (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#templating-assets), but this also requires you to put your folder under projects *web/*-directory so it could be accessed by symfony and webserver (in combination).

Since you're using a linux, it's simple as that:

```
cd /var/www/html/<projname>/
ln -s upload web/upload
```

Now you can simply reference to your assets like:

```
{{ asset('upload/somefolder/image.png') }}
```